# Automatically show which tags were edited in revision history

Tags: feature-request, tags

I’ve developed the habit of using the revision summary to indicate which changes I’ve made to the tags while retagging a question.

For instance, if the question originally had tags [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) [touch](/questions/tagged/touch) and it should be [cocoa-touch](/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) instead, I write the following in the revision summary:

> Edited tags: -cocoa, -touch, +cocoa-touch

which I find useful (and potentially educational) for the OP and other editors.

On the other hand, when an editor doesn’t type a revision summary, Stack Overflow shows

> User (timestamp) edited tags

with no indication of the difference between previous tags and the tags set by that edit.

Since there’s a limit on the number of tags, this difference would easily fit in the revision history list of that question. Could this be automatic in case the editor doesn’t fill the revision summary? Is it worth it?

Comment: It does [show added tag as green color in revision history](http://i.imgur.com/WCYpv.png), doesn't it enough?

Comment: @YOU Not for me. Does that depend on reputation?

Comment: @Bavarious - I don't think so, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5675535/revisions

Comment: @YOU I’m feeling dumb now. How did you get to that page? I couldn’t find a link in the original question/edit page.

Comment: @Bavarious, click "X mins ago" above your name on the question you edited.

Comment: @YOU Ha! Thanks. Should I remove this question?

Comment: @Bavarious, Imm, I am not sure, but probably I would just leave it.

Comment: Pre-filling the edit revision summary itself with tags changed would be separate to the highlighting, and the comments shouldn't negate that good idea